# App freezes while creating custom textfield in ios swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am try to develop a custom textbox in swift iOS, it's freezing after typing 2 letters

```
class TextField: UITextField , UITextFieldDelegate {
let inset: CGFloat = 10
let radius: CGFloat = 2
let borderWidth: CGFloat = 1

override init() {
    super.init()


}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    //self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(netHex:0xe5e5e5).CGColor
    self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    self.delegate = self
}

// placeholder position
override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRectInset(bounds , inset , inset)
}

// text position
override func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRectInset(bounds , inset , inset)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true

}
```

}

Here is the code, I found some answers that say setting delegate of the textfield to itself is not a good idea, but they didn't tell what is good idea. Can you please help me on this issue?

I need this three function behavior for all the textFields, what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: You can't just throw some lines of code in here and expect us to debug it. Please do some research and debugging yourself (e.g. don't set the textfield delegate to itself but to a proper class that implements `UITextFieldDelegate`)

Comment: An object should never be it's own delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the delegate to the view controller that uses the textfield not in your subclass.

```
textfield.delegate = self //self == view controller;
```

Remember to register your view controller as a delegate and add the delegate methods to your view controller's implementation file.

Answer (score 2):

when i click on textfield app freeze and stop working his problem still exists on Xcode 11.1 The solution is:

"Hardware -> Restart"

then running normally try this